# How to call Jquery from the results of another function

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery and a library called [collapser](http://www.aakashweb.com/demos/jquery-collapser/). It works fine.

I now need to update the page and can't make this more dynamic - I want to be display certain content based upon the selction of a drop down list. However, I can't get the collapser jQuery to work, the collapse ability doesn't function (the link doesn't show up)

```
<!-- please make a selection from the drop down list -->

<select id="ddl" >
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<div class='collapse'>1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br /></div><!--you can see this (kind of) works. The word hide exists and when clicked, it 'hides' (it's faulty but the word 'hides' is still shown)-->

<hr />

<div id="results"></div>
```

And the JavaScript

```
 $('#ddl').change(function() {
 document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<div class='collapseJs'>11<br />12<br />13<br />14<br />15<br /></div>";
});

$(document).ready(function(){$('.collapse').collapser({
mode: 'lines',
truncate: 3,
ellipsis: '...',
hideText: 'Hide',
showText: 'Show all',
atStart: 'show'
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){$('.collapseJs').collapser({
mode: 'lines',
truncate: 3,
ellipsis: '...',
hideText: 'Hide',
showText: 'Show all',
atStart: 'show'
});
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6t7jy/6/

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? Where when the user changes the selection, the new text is displayed but the collapser jquery still operates.

Comment: The `.collapseJS` div exists only after you fire the change event, and not when you're trying to run the collapser on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting script when you're firing the `change()`

```
$('#ddl').change(function () {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<div class='collapseJs'>1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br /></div>";
    $('.collapseJs').collapser({ //Added event of collapser
        mode: 'lines',
        truncate: 3,
        ellipsis: '...',
        hideText: 'Hide',
        showText: 'Show all',
        atStart: 'show'
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6t7jy/10/)